# "sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction) current transaction is aborted

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I wrote API using Flask-SQLAlchemy which sometimes throws error "sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction) current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block" and I'm using PostgreSQL & docker containe and Ass is the sample model.
Here is my code.

```
@APP.route('/get_ass_info/<int:ass_id>', methods=["GET"])
def get_ass_info(ass_id):
    item = Ass.query.filter_by(main_ass_id=ass_id).first()
    ag_list = []
    if item:
        if item.sponsor != 0:
            sp_obj =Ass.query.filter_by(main_ass_id=item.sponsor).first()
            sp_name = sp_obj.name
        else:
            sp_name = 'NA'
        dob_new = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(item.dob), "%Y-%m-%d")
        today = datetime.date.today()
        age = today.year - dob_new.year
        st_obj = State.query.filter_by(id=item.ag_state).first()
        if st_obj:
            state_name = st_obj.name
            state_id = st_obj.id
            old_state_id = st_obj.old_state_id
        else:
            state_name = ''
            state_id = 0
            old_state_id = 0
        dist_obj = District.query.filter_by(id=item.ag_district).first()
        if dist_obj:
            dist_name = dist_obj.name
            dist_id = dist_obj.id
            old_dist_id = dist_obj.old_district_id
        else:
            dist_name = ''
            dist_id = 0
            old_dist_id = 0
        ass_dict = {'ass_id':item.id, 'name':item.name, 'rank': item.asslevel.name if 
                      item.agentlevel_id != None else '', 
                      'city':item.city if item.city != 'null' and item.city != None and 
                       item.city !='None' else '',
                      'mobile':item.mobile_no, 'sponsor':item.sponsor, 'state':state_name,
                      'title':item.title,'ag_state':old_state_id,'ag_district':old_dist_id}
        ag_list.append(ass_dict)
        response = jsonify(ag_list)
        response.status_code = 200
        return response
    else:
        response = jsonify(ag_list)
        response.status_code = 200
        return response
```

If anyone knows the solution then let me know.

Comment: This usually means that the SQL query before the one that raised the error has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this in try except block and in except rollback transaction, this worked for me i was facing same issue.